# How to make a double y axis graph in R showing different scales

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a little problem in R trying to plot 3 different variables in a plot. My data frame is `Data` and it has 4 variables named `Month`, `Monto Otorgado acumulado`, `% Vencida` and `% Castigos`. `Data` has the next form (I add the `dput()` version of `Data` in the last part):

```
   Month  Monto Otorgado acumulado % Vencida  % Castigos
1 abr 13                 560492.3 0.000000000 0.01427317
2 may 13                1433973.4 0.007937344 0.01046045
3 jun 13                3016748.7 0.012917208 0.09281516
4 jul 13                4241217.7 0.032433503 0.07073440
5 ago 13                6251742.3 0.039709465 0.03039153
6 sep 13                6757161.2 0.055510741 0.05179690
7 oct 13                7408081.0 0.052154108 0.02024816
8 nov 13                7899980.3 0.051551260 0.02531652
```

Where `Month` shows a specific month of year, `Monto Otorgado acumulado` has values until 7 million, `% Vencida` and `% Castigos` are percentages. I am trying to make a graphic in R that shows two y axis. First y axis will show a scale considering the values of `Monto Otorgado acumulado` and second y axis will show a scale considering the values of `% Vencida` and `% Castigos` that are percentages. Variable `Month` is used in x axis to show what happen with variables `Monto Otorgado acumulado`, `% Vencida` and `% Castigos`. I have a little idea about plotting only one variable in ggplot but in this case is so complex for me. I wish to get a graphic like this:

[image]

The `dput()` version of `Data` is the next:

```
structure(list(Month = c("abr 13", "may 13", "jun 13", "jul 13", 
"ago 13", "sep 13", "oct 13", "nov 13"), `Monto Otorgado acumulado` = c(560492.29, 
1433973.37, 3016748.66, 4241217.73, 6251742.27, 6757161.24, 7408081.05, 
7899980.33), `% Vencida` = c(0, 0.00793734405263048, 0.0129172080248807, 
0.0324335034787285, 0.0397094648625047, 0.0555107413716237, 0.0521541081141384, 
0.0515512600016815), `% Castigos` = c(0.0142731668976214, 0.010460445301017, 
0.0928151568317925, 0.0707344020275045, 0.0303915279604129, 0.0517968992552855, 
0.0202481585970229, 0.0253165187311296)), .Names = c("Month", 
"Monto Otorgado acumulado", "% Vencida", "% Castigos"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a deliberate design decision that producing secondary axes is extremely difficult with ggplot2. Hadley considers them to be evil. There are some advanced hacks (e.g., I have seen one that could be used for this in an answer by @baptiste on SO), but those are not advertised. I suggest to not use secondary axes, but if you must it would be easier to use a different graphics package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Roland I edit my post only considering R, I know ggplot sometimes can be complex and it is a problem

Comment: Please show your own attempts.

Comment: I am very new with graphics in R I have a little knowledge of ggplot but in this case I only know how to plot my variables one by one using `barplot(Data$'Monto Otorgado acumulado')`, `plot(Data$'% Vencida',type="line")` and `plot(Data$'% Castigos',type="line")` that is the reason of my question @Roland

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in `base`, but it is a little annoying. You have to calculate the ratio between your left axis and right axis (like in your case, you want 9000000 on the left to be 14% on the right). You can use `points` and `lines` to get the `barplot` and `plot` on the same device:

```
par(mar=c(5,5,2,3)+0.1)
ratio<-9e6/0.14
bar.col<-'#558ED5'
vencido.col<-'#77933C'
castigos.col<-'#FE0F0F'
b<-barplot(Data$'Monto Otorgado acumulado',names.arg=Data$Month,col=bar.col,border=FALSE,main='My Plot',ylim=c(0,9e6),axes=FALSE)
lines(b,Data$'% Vencida' * ratio, col=vencido.col,lwd=2) 
points(b,Data$'% Vencida' * ratio, col=vencido.col,bg='white',pch=21) 
lines(b,Data$'% Castigos' * ratio, col=castigos.col,lwd=2)
points(b,Data$'% Castigos' * ratio, col=castigos.col,bg='white',pch=21)
left.axis.pos<-seq(0,9e6,by=1e6)
axis(2,at=left.axis.pos,labels=formatC(left.axis.pos, big.mark = ",", format = "d"),las=2)
right.axis.ticks<-0:14
axis(4,at=(right.axis.ticks/100)*ratio,labels=paste0(right.axis.ticks,'%'),las=2)
legend('topleft',legend=c('Monto Otorgado acumulado','% Vencido','% Castigos'),col=c(bar.col,vencido.col,castigos.col),lty=1,lwd=c(4,2,2),bty='n')
par(mar=c(5,4,2,2)+0.1)
```

[image]